# 2D triangulation

Tags: geometry, circles, triangulation, floating-point

I understood what it is from the following link:

http://electronics.howstuffworks.com/gadgets/travel/gps1.htm

But I want to know :

In a 2D plane, if we know the (x, y) positions of three “guard” points `a`, `b`, `c` and the distances of a point `p` to `a`, `b`, `c` – say `da`, `db`, `dc` – how to know the (x, y) position of point `p`

Given `a`,`b`,`c`, and `da`,`db`,`dc` . How to find the point `p`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Three-circle intersection for circles of unbounded integer radius](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110309/three-circle-intersection-for-circles-of-unbounded-integer-radius)  This shows how to get the intersection points of a pair of circles.  If you get the two intersection points for two of your circles, the third circle will tell you which one you want.

Answer (score 2):

Geometrically speaking, it is straightforward: just draw the two circles with midpoints $a,\ b$, and lengths $d_a$ and $d_b$. Unless things go wrong, these two circles intersect in two points $p_1,p_2$. Now, just compare distances from $p_i$ to $c$ - again, exactly one should be $d_c$.

Analytically speaking, you can write out coordinates of your points $a = (x_a,y_a)$, etc. The conditions about distances translate into $d_a^2 = (x_a - x_p)^2 + (y_a - y_p)^2$, etc. These are three equations in two unknowns, so assuming they have a solution, it is almost certainly unique. Note that subtracting the equation for, say, $a$, from the remaining two equations you make them linear, and thus easy to solve in principle (the exact formula won't enlighten you much, I believe).

Note that much of the given data is redundant: given $d_a,\ d_b$, there are generally just $2$ values of $d_c$ that make sense!