# Finding a position of a Dot by having its distance to 3 other dots.

Tags: geometry

I'm Building a robot that must always know his position So We put 3 wireless senders to it and..... , So I searched And I found out [Three-circle intersection for circles of unbounded integer radius](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110309/three-circle-intersection-for-circles-of-unbounded-integer-radius) , How can I find the 4th Dot position by having its Distance to 3 dots that we know their position , Can you give a formula by having D1,D2,D3 (The distances to 3 dots) and having the position (x1,y1) for dot1 and (x2,y2) for dot2 and (x3,y3) for Dot3 ??? and the position of the 4th dot be (finalX,finaly) ?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** This is called [trilateration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trilateration). It involes solving the following system of equations:
$$\begin{cases}
(x - x_1)^2 + (y - y_1)^2 = D_1^2 \\
(x - x_2)^2 + (y - y_2)^2 = D_2^2 \\
(x - x_3)^2 + (y - y_3)^2 = D_3^2 \\
\end{cases}$$

Comment: By following the equation we reach this point that                 num = 3(x^2+y^2) - 2x(x1) - 2x(x2) - 2x(x3) - 2y(y1) - 2y(y2) - 2y(y3) And We can't finish the equtation (num is d1^2 + d2^2 + d3^2 that the things we could have calculated the other part was reduced by them like x1^2 and ...

Answer (score 0):

Since your distance measurements are not 100% accurate, the trilateration equations (see other answer) will probably not have any solution. You need to use some kind of Least Squares approach. 
 Possibly, you could have a scaling parameter, $c$, so that the distances are: $cD_1$, $cD_2$, and $cD_3$. This will ensure the existence of a solution to the system of equations.

Comment: Cause I Don't Know how does the least squares approach works can You talk more about it and how should I work with it to solve the problem ?

Comment: Least squares is probably a bad idea because of its tendency to emphasis the noise in noisy data.  I'd approach it using two distances for each circle (D +/- error) and find the overlapping region (if any).